# Looking for JEXL Filter feature

Tags: java, filtering, jexl

I know, I can do several things in [JEXL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/syntax.html), but unable to find **Filter** feature in it, which is indeed very useful.

How can I do something like

```
 var x=[{a:11,b=5},{a:1,b=15},{a:12,b=25},{a:4,b=35},{a:7,b=45}];

 return x[.a>10].b; // Which filters to {a:11,b=5} & {a:12,b=25}
                   // & hence returns [5,25]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all your syntax is not valid JEXL. I assume you meant this:

```
var x = [{'a':11,'b':5}, {'a':1,'b':15}, {'a':12,'b':25}, {'a':4,'b':35}, {'a':7,'b':45}];
```

Since you can call any Java method on any object in a JEXL script, you have (at least theoretically) full access to the Java Stream API.

However, the Stream API isn't directly available from a raw array and we can't just call `Arrays.stream(x);` without some effort. The easiest way around this is to create a set instead:

```
var x = {{'a':11,'b':5}, {'a':1,'b':15}, {'a':12,'b':25}, {'a':4,'b':35}, {'a':7,'b':45}};
```

Now we can simply call `stream()` and work from there:

```
x.stream();
```

What we want now is something like this:

```
x.stream().filter(function(m){m['a']>10});
```

Unfortunately the method resolver in JEXL will not be able to correctly resolve `Stream.filter(Predicate)` with a JEXL function, as it doesn't know how to turn a JEXL function into a `Predicate`. A JEXL function is of type `org.apache.commons.jexl3.internal.Closure`.

Thus the very least you need to do is to provide your own `Predicate` implementation in Java and then create a new instance in your script:

```
public class MyCustomFilterPredicate implements Predicate<HashMap<String, Integer>> {
    @Override
    public boolean test(final HashMap<String, Integer> m)
    {
        return m.get("a") > 10;
    }
}
```

You can then create a new instance in your JEXL script:

```
var filterPredicate = new('my.custom.filter.predicate.MyCustomFilterPredicate');
```

The same goes for `Stream.map(Function)`:

```
public class MyCustomMapFunction implements Function<HashMap<String, Integer>, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(final HashMap<String, Integer> m)
    {
        return m.get("b");
    }
}
```

And again create a new instance in your script:

```
var mapFunction = new('my.custom.map.function.MyCustomMapFunction');
```

Your entire script will then look like this:

```
var x = {{'a':11,'b':5}, {'a':1,'b':15}, {'a':12,'b':25}, {'a':4,'b':35}, {'a':7,'b':45}};

var filterPredicate = new('my.custom.filter.predicate.MyCustomFilterPredicate');
var mapFunction = new('my.custom.map.function.MyCustomMapFunction');

return x.stream().filter(filterPredicate).map(mapFunction).toArray();
```

Of course you might have noticed that the reusability of your predicate and function implementations are rather limited. This is why I'd recommend creating implementations that wrap a JEXL Closure:

```
public class MyCustomFilterPredicate implements Predicate<Object> {
    private final Closure closure;
    public MyCustomFilterPredicate(final Closure closure) {
        this.closure = closure;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean test(final Object o)
    {
        return (boolean) closure.execute(JexlEngine.getThreadContext(), o);
    }
}

public class MyCustomMapFunction implements Function<Object, Object> {
    private final Closure closure;
    public MyCustomMapFunction(final Closure closure) {
        this.closure = closure;
    }
    @Override
    public Object apply(final Object o)
    {
        return closure.execute(JexlEngine.getThreadContext(), o);
    }
}
```

Now you can change your script as follows and reuse these Java classes in various ways:

```
var x = {{'a':11,'b':5}, {'a':1,'b':15}, {'a':12,'b':25}, {'a':4,'b':35}, {'a':7,'b':45}};

var filterPredicate = new('my.custom.filter.predicate.MyCustomFilterPredicate', function(m){m['a']>10});
var mapFunction = new('my.custom.map.function.MyCustomMapFunction', function(m){m['b']});

return x.stream().filter(filterPredicate).map(mapFunction).toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed answer. By the way I am developing a scripting language for less technical user, is there an easier way to access such filters rather than providing in function(){} way ?

Comment: With plain JEXL, no. But of course there's always some way, depending on how far you're willing and able to go. You could for example expand on the JEXL library and write your own parser that adds some sugars. Or you might want to look into something like xtext instead, it let's you develop your own languages somewhat easily. However that would most certainly go beyond the scope of this question. Good luck!

Comment: Can we extend JEXL parser? Actually I tried but couldn't find a way to do so, though I could override operators.

Comment: Well, it's open source, so of course you can. But I suggest asking a new question for this.